# How can I find the RepeaterItem I have clicked?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a simple ASP page that has a Repeater control. This repeater control contains LinkButtons; so that as the repeater increases in item size, the amount of LinkButtons also increases. My question is, how can I identify uniquely the RepeaterItem to which I click the LinkButton?.

I though of using a Foreach to search through the RepeaterItems but I don't know what conditions should I use to identify the Linkbutton I cliked. By the way, each LinkButton have the same name and same ID.

My goal is to get the RepeaterItem in which that Linkbutton belongs

Thanks,
Y_Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Assign Command/ComandArgument for your LinkButton
- Assign handler 'OnCommand' for your Repeater and create event handler
- In the handler you get RepeaterCommandEventArgs - use item property to access

Comment: Also, with your solution I will probably get the Linkbutton. My goal was to get the RepeaterItem in which that Linkbutton belongs.

Comment: @Y_Y per msdn: "Item - Gets the RepeaterItem associated with the event." - so don't worry you get not a LinkButton. For example look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatercommandeventargs.aspx#Y900

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
- Tag property of LinkButton to store object to identify the LinkButton 
- Included hidden field in Repeater template to store something to identify Linkbutton.
- Using CommandArgument of LinkButton
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using what is called "ItemCommand"

or you can set the CommandArgument of your LinkButton.

```
protected void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    LinkButton _sender = (LinkButton)sender;
    string argument = _sender.CommandArgument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The common solution for this scenario is to use the CommandName and/or CommandArgument properties of the button. Just bind the CommandArgument to the ID of the objects you put into the repeater. The command argument can be accessed in the click handler.